# Mocking twilio with mockito

Tags: java, oop, unit-testing, mockito, twilio

I'm writing a unit test for a method what returns true if a sub account is already found on my twilio account. I'm trying to mock this with Mockito but get cast errors casting List to AccountList. I looked through the mockito documentation but might have missed something.

This is the test:

```
        @Mock
TwilioRestClient client;

@Mock
AccountList accountList;

@Mock
Iterator<Account> iterator;

@Mock
Account account;

@Test
public void testShouldReturnTrueIfAccountNameFound() {
        final List<Account> list = Arrays.asList(account);

        when(client.getAccounts()).thenReturn((AccountList) list);
        when(account.getFriendlyName()).thenReturn("test");
        when(accountList.iterator()).thenReturn(list.iterator());
    MyTwilioAccountStore store = null;
    store = new MyTwilioAccountStore(client);

    Assert.assertTrue(store.subAccountExists("test"));  
}
```

And this is the method I'm testing. I'm injecting the TwilioRestClient in the constructor.

```
        /**
 * class constructor
 * 
 * @param client
 */
public MyTwilioAccountStore(TwilioRestClient client) {
    fClient = client;
}


/**
 * rest client getter
 * 
 * @return RESTClient
 */
public TwilioRestClient getRestClient() {
    return fClient;
}
     /**
 * Check if a sub account already exists
 * 
 * @param friendlyName
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean subAccountExists(String friendlyName) {
    // Build a filter for the AccountList
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("FriendlyName", friendlyName);
    AccountList accounts = getRestClient().getAccounts(params);

    // Loop over accounts
            // This is where I get NPE
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (account.getFriendlyName().equalsIgnoreCase(friendlyName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is the getAccounts of the Twilio source code:

```
    /**
 * Get all accounts. For more info: {@link <a
 * href="http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/account"
 * >http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/account</a>}
 *
 * @return the list of accounts.
 */
public AccountList getAccounts() {
    return this.getAccounts(new HashMap<String, String>());
}
```

How can I mock the AccountList correctly?

Comment: Where do you get your NPE?

Comment: Excuse me but you have to clarify, what's NPE in this context?

Comment: It seems that the client has a `.getAccounts(Map<String, String>())` method somewhere, am I right? What are the access modifiers of this method?

Comment: Can you show, or at least provide a link to, the prototype of `AccountList`?

Comment: Sure, here's the source for AccountList, a bit long to post here. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/sdk/resource/list/AccountList.java

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** It seems the real problem here is to be able to mock `AccountList`, as returned from the twilio client...

**EDIT CONTINUED** If, as I suspect, this class implements `Iterable<Account>`, then what is needed is to build a single element list with a mock `Account`, and have `accountList.iterator()` return an `Iterator` of the list created above

---

### Original answer

You mock:

```
when(accountList.iterator().next())
```

But when you are using a foreach loop, the first thing called is `.iterator()` itself -- and you have no mock for that. As a return, mockito performs the default action: returning `null` (to be honest, I am really surprised that it didn't even throw an exception here telling "sorry, can't do that" since it is a chained method call!).

You should:

```
when(accountList.iterator()).thenReturn(anIterator);
```

where `anIterator` is an actual iterator, complete with `.hasNext()`, `.next()` and `.remove()`.

Since you seem to be wanting to use a mock for your account too, I guess your list should be set up as such:

```
final List<Account> accountList = Arrays.asList(account);
```

Which gives:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnTrueIfAccountNameFound() 
{
    final List<Account> list = Arrays.asList(account);

    when(account.getFriendlyName()).thenReturn("test");
    when(accountList.iterator()).thenReturn(list.iterator());

    final MyTwilioAccountStore store = new MyTwilioAccountStore(client);

    Assert.assertTrue(store.subAccountExists("test"));  
}
```

Comment: hm, I'll try this. I edited my question with a more up to date version of my try. It still gives an NPE. I will try this approach if it's possible. List might not be castable to AccountList. Give me a moment.

Comment: That's not it! From your code I see that `AccountList` implements `Iterable<Account>`, am I not right?

Comment: tried your approach but still get an NPE. Weird. I have updated my question to reflect how it looks.

Comment: OK, then you need to make your `client` return an actual list on `.getAccounts()`...

Comment: yeah, I did that which gives me cast problems. Is mocking the way to go here? Thanks for helping, really.

Comment: Cast problems?? Uh... Mind updating your question with that cast problem you are talking about?

Comment: Can you mock an `AccountList`?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do basically. Mock AccountList so that the iterator contains one mock of Account returning a test value on getFriendlyName :)

Comment: See my comment: what is the prototype of `AccountList`? Does it implement `Iterable<Account>` by any chance?  If you can mock it then you win

Comment: There's a couple of layers of inheritance going on in AccountList.. and it implements the interface AccountFactory (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/sdk/resource/factory/AccountFactory.java)

Comment: I am calling it a day, will continue tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you're doing this wrong.  Just because you say `@Mock` on a field, doesn't mean that anything that instantiates that same type of class will get it.  You need to find a way for the `getRestClient()` to return *your* mock.  If it returns a `new AccountList`, that won't be your mock, and it will probably cause these problems.

Show us the `getRestClient()` method and I can help more.

---

OK, you have a `getAccounts()` method that you're mocking with this line:

```
    when(client.getAccounts()).thenReturn((AccountList) list);
```

But the system under test calls this line:

```
    AccountList accounts = getRestClient().getAccounts(params);
```

See the difference here?  The actual method that gets called takes in a `Map`, but you're not mocking that method.  You need to change your when above to something like this:

```
    when(client.getAccounts(any(Map.class))).thenReturn((AccountList) list);
```

In other words, you're mocking the wrong method.  By default Mockito will return sensible defaults and in this case, that happens to be `null`.  If `getAccounts()` returned an Integer/int, it would return 0.

Comment: getRestClient is just a getter for the variable client which gets set in the constructor as the value of the injected TwilioRestClient.

Comment: @Phil edit your original question to show us.  I need to see the NullPointerException, I need to see what line it's occurring on, I need to see how `getAccounts()` works.  This is not enough info.

Comment: Updated the question. Added a comment where the NPE happens, it's when  accounts gets iterated upon. Thanks for helping

Comment: @Phil that was a typo.  use `any(Map.class)`

Comment: @Phil if you `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;` it'll be available to you

Comment: Ah wonderful. Thanks. However, I get type casting problems as well, as AccountList is not castable to list. I will continue investigating.

Comment: @Phil sounds like a different issue.  I don't know why you're trying to cast it in the first place.  I don't think you were at first.

Comment: I wanted to inject a list containing the mock of an account. But that isn't necessarily the right way to do this. I am a bit green in this area though, so I don't know the best practice way of dealing with mockito here. Feel free to suggest a better way :)

Comment: I am calling it a day, will continue tomorrow. Thanks for your help!